# userInterfaceIdiom returning wrong values on real devices

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uidevice

My app was rejected because there is a problem on the iPad UI of my app. I have fixed it before this getting rejected by checking if the device was an iPad to make some minor adjustments to the UI measures. The problem is that when I call:

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom //returns .Unspecified
traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom //returns -1
```

On a real iPad I get .Unspecified. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this I have created a custom method which actually works on a real iPad

```
public extension UIDevice {

func isIpadDevice() -> Bool {
    let identifier = deviceIdentifier()

    return identifier.lowercaseString.containsString("ipad")
}

private func deviceIdentifier() -> String {
    var systemInfo = utsname()
    uname(&systemInfo)
    let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)
    let identifier = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
        guard let value = element.value as? Int8 where value != 0 else { return identifier }
        return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
    }

    return identifier
}
```

}

In order to use it call

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().isIpadDevice() //wohoo
```